I receive null after Model Binding
I receive variable with null values after model binding. What might be wrong here? Title is null, content is null after form submitting.
Create.cshtml
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-custom">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </form>

PostViewModel.cs
namespace ForumApp.ViewModels
{
    public class PostViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}

Post.cs
namespace ForumApp.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = [];
    }
}

Create action
        // POST: Posts/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PostViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var post = new Post
                {
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Content = model.Content,
                    UserId = user.Id
                };
                _context.Add(post);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(model);
        }


Even without ViewModel it was not working, adding [Bind("Title,Content")] didn't help. That's everything I receive:


Can you show code of the action method that renders the view and include the model declaration @model in the view, please?

Here's the action method:
    // GET: Posts/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

And here's model declaration in view:
@model ForumApp.ViewModels.PostViewModel

Have you tried using [FromForm] in your HttpPost method for model binding?

@SoftwareDveloper
Yeah, but it didn't help

Thank you all for your suggestions! :) I've found a solution:
Everything you need, is to change


to
Title

Then do the same for 'Content' property.

If it works with <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" /> but not with <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />, it may be because you didn't add tag helpers to your project. Check if you have a file called _ViewImports.cshtml in your Views folder with the following content:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers


Exactly! I figured it out yesterday, but thank you.


I receive variable with null values after model binding. What might be wrong here? Title is null, content is null after form submitting.

Based on your code snippet and description, I have tried to investigate your issue and during the simulation I have just used your view and controller code. And it seems I am getting the correct value in Title and Content property.
I am not sure if you haven't shared your ViewModel reference within your view by mistake or not. Without that reference, I think everything is alright.
I have tried following way and getting the correct value:
View:
@model PostViewModel

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-custom">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</form>


Noted: Added the @model PostViewModel reference within the view which your shared view is missing.
Controller:
Controller code is almost same, I have removed a few unnecessary code items in order to test the scenario, you could include them.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PostViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(model);
}

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document for model validation details here.
